# ngDialog - Difference between open and openConfirm

Tags: angularjs, ng-dialog

I only know open and openConfirm has little difference on the default options when opening a dialog, like openConfirm Opens a dialog that by default does not close when hitting escape or clicking outside the dialog window. 
Do they have any other differences? Can anyone help to summary it a little bit.

I also want to know when should i use open, and when should i use the openConfirm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use Open function, you can only open a page without waiting the user to confirm your message : [Open Function](https://github.com/likeastore/ngDialog#openoptions)

The openConfirm let you to open a dialog that by default does not close when hitting escape or clicking outside the dialog window. The function returns a promise that is either resolved or rejected depending on the way the dialog was closed. : [OpenConfirm Function](https://github.com/likeastore/ngDialog#openconfirmoptions)